# How get Id after run "insert" great data using executeBatch()

Tags: java, jdbc

This is a resume my code:

```
cf.getConnection().setAutoCommit(false);
PreparedStatement ps = 
cf.getConnection().prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT_TC, 
Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

for (TesteCaseTSBean testCase : testCases) {
ps.setString(1, testCase.getTestPlan());
ps.setString(2, testCase.getSTIPRJ());
ps.setString(3, testCase.getFase());
ps.setString(4, testCase.getTestPhase());
ps.setString(5, testCase.getTestScriptName());
ps.setString(6, testCase.getTestScriptDescription());
ps.setString(7, testCase.getStepDescription());
ps.setString(8, testCase.getExpectedResults());
ps.setString(9, testCase.getProduct());
ps.setTimestamp(10, new 
java.sql.Timestamp(testCase.getDataPlanejada().getTime()));
ps.setString(11, testCase.getNumeroCenario());
ps.setString(12, testCase.getNumeroCt());
ps.setString(13, testCase.getComplexidade());
ps.setBoolean(14, testCase.isAutomatizado());
ps.setString(15, testCase.getCenario());
ps.setBoolean(16, testCase.isRework());
ps.setBoolean(17, testCase.isPriority());
ps.setBoolean(18, testCase.isRegression());
ps.setBoolean(19, testCase.isData());
ps.setInt(20, testCase.getIdSystem());
ps.setString(21, testCase.getCreatedBy());
ps.setString(22, testCase.getModifiedBy());
ps.setTimestamp(23, new 
java.sql.Timestamp(testCase.getModifyDate().getTime()));
ps.setTimestamp(24, new 
java.sql.Timestamp(testCase.getCreateDate().getTime()));
ps.setInt(25, testCase.getOrder());
ps.setInt(26, testCase.getIdTestPlanTS());
ps.addBatch();

int[] row = ps.executeBatch();

ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
```

When run `ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();` the error is returned:

> The statement must be executed before any results can be obtained.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55985165/2970947

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Can you help me with a solution? Thanks!

Comment: Which database and which driver are you using. Support for generated keys with batch execution is not required by JDBC so support depends on the driver (and database).